# Combining CSV files of simulation results

Tags: python, python-2.x, file-system, csv, pandas

This script is a subset of a larger script where I have the output of many test simulations in the form of CSVs. Each file starts with the model name and includes the number of elements in my file. For example, `edge_16elem_out.csv` would be a first-order model (edge) with 16 elements. Another example would be `edge3_1024elem_out.csv`. I have created several helper functions and am curious if there are ways to improve this code. I am using Python 2.7.

````py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
import re

def k(x, q=1200, g=1, l=11, k=3, t0=300):
    """Analytic Computation - Equation can be found in ./heat_source_bar.i"""
    return  ((q - np.exp(-g * l) * x * q * g - np.exp(-g * x) * q) / (k * g)) + t0

def slope(x, y):
    """Computes slope in log-log terms"""
    return (y.diff() / x.diff()).fillna(0)

def compute_error(analytic, simulation):
    """Error Computation - calculates a percentage from simulated answer to analytical answer"""
    return np.log10(np.abs((analytic - simulation) / analytic))

def get_basename(fp):
    """Fetches basename of a given file path w/ file extension truncated"""
    return os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(fp))[0]

def get_model_num(fp):
    """Extracts number of radial elements from given file path
    (Ex. edge3_16elem_out.csv will return 16)"""
    var = str(get_basename(fp).split('_')[1])
    return int(re.search(r'\d+', var).group(0))

def get_model_type(fp, prefix):
    """Helper function to be able to get different model
    types by determining model type from file path prefix"""
    return filter(lambda x: get_basename(x).startswith(prefix), fp)

def read_assign(fp, model_id):
    """Read in csv and create column assigning model number as column"""
    return pd.read_csv(fp).assign(model_id=model_id)

def main():
    working_dir = os.path.abspath('.')
    file_paths = glob.glob(os.path.join(working_dir, '*_out.csv'))

    edge_files = get_model_type(file_paths, 'edge_')
    edge_ids = map(get_model_num, edge_files)

    edge_sol = (pd.concat(map(read_assign, edge_files, edge_ids))
                .sort_values('model_id')
                .query('time == 1')
                .assign(points = [5.5 for x in range(11)])
                .assign(t_sol = lambda x: k(x.points)))

    edge_err = (edge_sol
                .assign(t_err = compute_error(edge_sol.t_sol, edge_sol.point),
                        log_model_id = np.log10(1/edge_sol.model_id))
                .assign(slope = lambda x: slope(x.log_model_id, x.t_err)))

    edge_err.to_csv('edge_err.csv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```
````